# Mountain Lion Messages: Gmail user is not registered with iMessage

Tags: macos, messages

I'm trying to use Messages instead of Adium, but it won't let me chat with some of my contacts.

These aren't iMessage accounts, but gmail users. If I try to message them, I get a "address is not registered with iMessage." alert.  There doesn't seem to be any reason or method to it, either.  I've tried restarting iMessage as well as rebooting my machine.

Comment: You have to add a Google account in Messages first.

Comment: My apple.com account is a google account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Google account to the Messages app. After that, you can use Messages with GTalk.